# PHP Mailer: How can i see the information from the select options in my email

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

I am building a form to send email. It works fine with textareas and inputs but how can I do it with select options as well? Here is my code:

I have to declare the country variable that is commented and use the find jquery method to retrieve the name of the selection. Then I need to print the result in the php to see in the email the options

Form demo: https://treegrafting.herokuapp.com/blog/pages/budwood.php

**HTML** select options:

```
<select name="countryName" id="country" name="country">
  <option value="cy">Cyprus</option>
  <option value="gr">Greece</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

**Ajax**:

```
        var form = $('#contact');
        form.submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);


        var name= $form.find("input[name='firstname']").val();
        var email= $form.find("input[name='email']").val();
        var Message = $form.find("textarea[name=message]").val();
       // var country= ...

         $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../../sendemail.php',
                    data: {
                        Name: name,
                        Email: email,
                        message: Message
                    },
});
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST["message"]) && !empty($_POST["message"])) {

 $mymail=smtpmailer("email@gmail.com",$_POST['Email'], $_POST['Name'], $_POST[Subject],  $_POST['message']);


    function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) {
$mail->Body = "print here the options that the user selected"
```

Comment: `$form.find("select[name=countryName]").val();` would work fine. Btw, does this work? Shouldn't `$_POST[Subject]` be `$_POST['Subject']` ? You're also not setting the Subject anywhere.

Comment: @WillParky93 no, it is not a textarea it is options with selections, see the demo

Comment: My bad, I didn't read that so well, I edited but yet again I'm not sure. The answers provided offer a much better solution. How about my other point I raised about your $_POST[Subject]

Comment: I think I have to remove that it is a used code from an older form. I don't know if I have to. The variable subject is used in the $mail->Subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do the same:

```
var country= $("#country").val();
```

This is the shortest notation to get the value of the selected option. Note that I use the id of the select to choose it and get its value. No need to use find if you have an id for an element.

Just for reference you can find more details [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/).

In your ajax add the county;

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '../../sendemail.php',
     data: {
         Name: name,
         Email: email,
         message: Message,
         country: country
     },
```

in PHP you will just do

```
$country = $_POST['country'];
```

$country will have the value that correspond to the value of the selected option as defined in your html. So for example 'cy' or 'gr'.

Comment: I need to do something in php too, The left hand side of the ajax data has to do with php using $_POST[''];

Comment: No need to parse the variable inside the smtp mailer function? eg: function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $country, $body)

Comment: I don't know what do you want to do with the variable. I gave you the answer on how to handle it. Then you have to see if you want to concatenate it in the body or if you need it somewhere else in the code

Comment: I just got a bit confused with PHP, Because every information in the ajax is printed inside a function in php as parameter. That is why I am asking. I tried to Put it outside the parameter but inside the smtp mailer function to see if it works

Comment: He sends the emails through phpMailer. He can't just put $country = $_POST['country']; and work. He needs to configure the variables as parameters otherwise he will get an error

Comment: as i said before, the country value must be included in the subject or in the body of the email, not just added as a parameter to the function. My answer is just to get OP to the point of having the value in the php page.

Answer (score 0):

you can access directly value of select field using their id like
var country =$("#country").val();
and pass it to ajax parameter